# What is the single name for floor and ceiling?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there a single name for both closest integer neighbors (floor and ceiling) of a real number?

Examples:

`2` and `3` are both *THE_WORD* of `2.7`

`2` is the only *THE_WORD* of `2`

What is *THE_WORD*?

Comment: They are both rounding function.  Ceiling is rounding up and Floor is rounding down.  So I think it'd be acceptable to say "rounding to consecutive integers" or "rounding to within two integers".

Answer (score 2):

This is usually called [rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer).

Comment: This made me chuckle.

Comment: Would you say that *`2` and `3` are both rounds of `2.7`* ?

Comment: @TMG I would say 2.7 rounds up to 3 and rounds down to 2.